Cannibalism or Non Kosher
In a case of Pikuach Nefesh, for example, someones plane crashes on a deserted island and the only "edible" items are a dead human being or a pig, which one should that person eat?
There would be reason to assume that cannibalism is preferred as it's at worst a positive (עשה) transgression according to some, or even outright allowed (see here) vs. eating pig, which is an issur deoraysa. To keep the question focus, let's assume no blood will be consumed by eating the human.
Is there another way to approach this question?

Great question, but I gotta know: Why did you think of this?
